# Is there a way to make the connected printer the default printer in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

I generally use two printers, my HP printer at home, my Canon printer at work, both local printers connected via USB.

It is a minor pain to keep changing / selecting the right printer in the list in the Windows Default Printing Dialog Box  everyday.

At any given time only one printer is attached and that's the one I would want to print on by default.

Is there a way to make Windows realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into Devices and Printers. Select a printer and then choose `Manage default printers` from the top menu.

[image]

In the next window, select `Change default printer when I change networks`

[image]

Adjust the properties according by choosing the network and printer, then choose <kbd>Add</kbd>.  Now when you connect to a network, the printer you have chosen will be your default.

[source](http://www.howtogeek.com/58103/how-to-automatically-change-your-default-printer-based-on-your-location/)

Comment: Interesting thanks! But somehow I do not see that "Manage Default Printers" option at all. The other options from your screenshot, those I can see. Don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Hmmm...

Comment: You have to select the printer before the option is available. If you are not connected to the printer, it may not be available until you connect to that printer.